# How to convert this c code to c++ in opencv

Tags: opencv

I'm a starter in opencv, and Learning Opencv has is code written in C.
I need to convert to C++.

```
IplImage *imgY = cvCreateImage(imageSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);  
IplImage *imgCr = cvCreateImage(imageSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);  
IplImage *imgCb = cvCreateImage(imageSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);  
IplImage *imgYCrCb = cvCreateImage(imageSize, img->depth, img->nChannels); 

cvCvtColor(img,imgYCrCb,CV_BGR2YCrCb);  
cvSplit(imgYCrCb, imgY, imgCr, imgCb, 0);  

unsigned char *pY, *pCr, *pCb, *pMask;
pY = (unsigned char *)imgY->imageData;  
pCr = (unsigned char *)imgCr->imageData;  
pCb = (unsigned char *)imgCb->imageData;
pMask = (unsigned char *)mask->imageData;
```

Comment: Almost all C code is valid C++.  You'll need to be more specific than that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refer to:

- http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/c++_cheatsheet.html
- and http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=opencv_cheatsheet.pdf

For example,

```
IplImage *imgY = cvCreateImage(imageSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
```

becomes

```
cv::Mat imgY = cv::Mat(imageSize, CV_8UC1);
```

and

```
cvCvtColor(img,imgYCrCb,CV_BGR2YCrCb);
```

becomes

```
cv::cvtColor(img, imgYCrCb, CV_BGR2YCrCb);
```

and so on ...

Edit :

Answer to your comment : 
OpenCV 2 removes the need to manage manually the memory.

So, the code can be rewritten as :

```
cv::Mat imgYCrCb;
std::vector<cv::mat> yCrCb_channels;

cv::cvtColor(img,imgYCrCb,CV_BGR2YCrCb);   
cv::split(imgYCrCb, yCrCb_channels);
unsigned char * pY = (uchar *) yCrCn_channels[1].data;
```

Advice : read [http://www.amazon.com/dp/1849513244/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849513244) , it covers the C++ opencv interface.

Comment: My 1st problem is with split function. In c++ only accepts a vector. The 2nd problem is that i don't know how to make pY = (unsigned char *)imgY->imageData; in C++. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Pascal, are these also equal?     `//frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(depth_width, depth_height), 8, 3); // Create the frame
 cv::Mat frame = cv::Mat(cvSize(depth_width, depth_height), CV_8UC3);`

Comment: Hi Mona, better use `cv::Mat frame = cv::Mat(cv::Size(width, height), CV_8UC3)` . In summary, replace cvSize by cv::Size. Also, the name depth_width makes me wonders you might be confusing image depth vs image size.